# Set up page control with uiscrollview that is inside uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableViewController. In one of my prototype cells there is a UIScrollView with horizontal paging and a page control. I have set this up in **storyboard**, laying out all the elements that will display on each page of the UIScrollView, exactly how I have set a scroll view up in the past in a UIViewController. Since this UIScrollView is inside a UITableViewCell, I am confused about how to connect the page control.

1) Should the code to change the page control be in the cell class file? And if so what would that look like?

2) Also do I implement the UIScrollViewDelegate inside the UITableViewController or inside the UITableViewCell class file?

(this is in objective-c)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the `UIPageControl` code inside of the cell class seems to be the most appropriate choice. The view controller which is displaying the table/cells  shouldn't be delegating this type of internal behaviour.

If you're implementing the code in the cell class then the cell class would need to conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol in order to receive the `scrollViewDidScroll:` message. The table view controller wouldn't be involved.

This is what it the method would look like:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGFloat pageIndex = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame);
    self.pageControl.currentPage = lround(pageIndex);
}
```

Also make sure to set the pagingEnabled property on the scrollview to YES.

Comment: Thanks! I have my scrollViewDidScroll function as I have done a paged scroll view before, however I am not sure how to do this in the cell class. If I place this in the cell class, where do I call the function? And second question: where do I place the code for the scrollViewDidScroll pages themselves? That is, the data that will populate the pages. Previously I did this on the view controller that contained the scroll view.

Comment: So in the cell class you'd need to set the class as the delegate of the scrollview and implement the scrollViewDidScroll method in the cell class like you would do in a view controller, it would get called by the scroll view since it's a regular delegate method.

Comment: If the content of the scroll view is populated dynamically when the user scrolls then you can set the table view controller as the scroll view delegate for each cell's scrollview and then make the cell's scrollViewDidScroll method public, setup a new delegate method on the cell which (cellNeedsContentForPageAtIndex:), or easiest would be setup a block on the cell for configuring pages (void (^pageBlock)(id sender, NSInteger pageIndex)).

Comment: Ok I will try all this and let you know if it worked or come back w more questions if not. ;)

Comment: part of my answer got erased, should be:  setup a new delegate method on the cell which gets the called by the table views scrollViewDidScroll